# Suggestions on mail servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, smtp

I got a app sending massive newsletters and so far I been using the regular smtp within the iis7. I been looking at mail servers and There are plenty out there and I wonder what your tips and experiences are on this? What mail servers are good and easy to use with windows server 2008, iis7..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, what for? For sending emails I think the SMTP service is perfect. Otherwise...

- Exchange for companies for all the added benefit of NOT being ONLY an eamil server
- Smartertools "SmarterMail" for those trying not to spend that much money ;)

Comment: I'm sending out mass emails. I will check the SmarterMail. thanks

Comment: Still not needed. Windows SMTP Services is really all you DO need for SENDING.

Comment: I am sending minimum of 20k emails and it is getting larger all the time. Now I am afraid that the Win SMTP Service wont be able to handle it. How many emails the session can handle?

Comment: Why do you think the SMTP service wouldn't be able to handle it? While I'm always suspicious of anyone sending out that sort of volume the reality is that 20k emails is trifling. Just don't expect them all to go out at once.

Comment: PLus make sure the server is up to the task hardware wise - which may mean a nice fast disc (SSD) to handle all the disc io. But seriously, come back to another product when your email batches are a million emails large. 20.000 is something my phone could handle with a proper connection ;)